# Ackermann function $A(x,y)$: Prove that $A(4,y) = \underbrace{2^{2^{.^{\cdot^2}}}}_\textrm{y+3 times} -3$.

Tags: computability, recursion

Prove that $A(4,y) = \underbrace{2^{2^{.^{\cdot^2}}}}_\textrm{y+3 times} -3$.

I'm having trouble with proving that there are indeed $y+3$ exponentiations:

\begin{align*}
A(4,y) &= A(3, A(4,y-1))\\
&= 2^{A(4,y-1)+3}-3\\
&= 2^{2^{A(4,y-2)}-3+3}-3\\
&= 2^{2^{A(4,y-2)}}-3\\
&= 2^{2^{.^{.^{2^{A(4,0)}}}}}-3
\end{align*}

So far, according to my understanding, we have $y$ exponentiations. Now by considering that $A(4,0) = A(3,1) = 2^4-3 = 2^{2^2}-3$, we get additionally $2$ exponentiations for a a total of $b+2$.

Where is the missing exponent?

Comment: $A(4,0)$ according to your calculation, has $3$ twos. If we add those twos to the tower, the number of twos increases by $3$

Comment: You should prove the formula by induction over $y$

Comment: @Peter I also tried that but since $A(4,0) = 2^{2^2}-3$ we get a ''stack'' of $2$ twos instead of $0 +3 = 3$ as It should.

Comment: $2^{2^2}$ is a stack of $3$ twos ,  so $A(4,0)=2^{2^2}-3$ is correct. The base also counts!

Comment: @Peter Aaah. That explains the whole thing (:. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prove by induction that

$$A(1,n)=n+2$$

Use this to prove by induction that

$$A(2,n)=2(n+3)-3$$

Use this to prove by induction that

$$A(3,n)=2^{n+3}-3$$

And use this to prove by induction that

$$A(4,n)=^{n+3}2-3$$

where we used [tetration notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration).

$$\begin{align}A(4,n+1)&=A(3,A(4,n))\\&=2^{(^{n+3}2-3)+3}-3\\&=2^{(^{n+3}2)}-3\\&=^{n+4}2-3\end{align}$$

Thus, it holds by induction.

---

As a bonus, see if you can prove by induction that

$$A(k,n)=2\uparrow^{k-2}(n+3)-3$$

where we use [Knuth's up-arrow notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_up-arrow_notation).